# Use React Functional Component to index.html standalone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

**What has been done?**

- I have created functional component and exported as "CustomButton" in index.js

**What is needed?**

- I need to embed such multiple component to index.html file and use it.

**What is the problem?**

- I have used react project so it was working well but as I need to use the same as web page, I needed create build to support in browsers,
- I followed all steps to create build and use bundle file into web page. but when I use it as ReactDOM.render(`<CustomButton />`,root reference) it gives and error of it is not defined.

I am not sure how to use it after creating bundle.

Example code

**index.html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html />
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"> </script>
  <script src="require.js"> </script>
  <script>var exports = {"__esModule": true};</script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/jsx">
            ReactDOM.render(<CustomButton />, document.getElementById('root'));
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**WebPackConfig:**

```js
const path = require("path");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./index.js",
  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: 'html-loader',
        options: {
          interpolate: true,
          esModule: true
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|config\.js$|manifest\.json$)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
          plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"]
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|svg|gif)$/,
        exclude: /launcher-icon/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[hash].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'assets/img/'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /(\.jsonx$)/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].json',
              outputPath: ''
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(dust)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'dust-loader-complete',
          options: {
            preserveWhitespace: true
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp3|mp4)$/,
        use: [
          //'file-loader'
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[hash].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'assets/snd/'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[hash].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'assets/fonts/'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: "index.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    library: "",
    globalObject: 'this'
  }
};
```

Let me know if more information needed. Thanks in advance